# Telegram webhook php bot doesn't answer

Tags: php, webhooks, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to set up a telegram bot with a webhook. I can get it to work with getUpdates, but I want it to work with a webhook.

My site (that hosts the bot php script) has the SSL certificate working (I get the green lock in the address bar):

I set up the webhook with

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/setwebhook?url=https://www.example.com/bot/bot.php
```

And I got: {"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}

(I don't know if this matters, but I have given rwx rights to both the folder and the script)

The php bot: (https://www.example.com/bot/bot.php)

```
<?php

$botToken = <token>;
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

#$update = url_get_contents('php://input');
$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);

$chatId = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$message = $update["message"]["text"];

switch($message) {
    case "/test":
        sendMessage($chatId, "test");
        break;
    case "/hi":
        sendMessage($chatId, "hi there!");
        break;
    default:
        sendMessage($chatId, "default");
}

function sendMessage ($chatId, $message) {
    $url = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($message);
    url_get_contents($url);

}

function url_get_contents($Url) {
    if(!function_exists('curl_init')) {
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

?>
```

But when I write anything to the bot I receive no answers...

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your question it's not clear the script location. Seeing your code, it seems that you try to load a request through `url_get_contents` to retrieve telegram server response. This is the correct method if your bot works **without** webhook. Otherwise, after setting webhook, you have to process **incoming** requests.

I.e., if you set webhook to `https://example.com/mywebhook.php`, in your `https://example.com/mywebhook.php` script you have to write something like this:

```
<?php

$request = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
#          ↑↑↑↑ 
$request = json_decode( $request, TRUE );

if( !$request )
{
    // Some Error output (request is not valid JSON)
}
elseif( !isset($request['update_id']) || !isset($request['message']) )
{
    // Some Error output (request has not message)
}
else
{
    $chatId  = $request['message']['chat']['id'];
    $message = $request['message']['text'];

    switch( $message )
    {
        // Process your message here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I set up the webhook exactly like your example, and made I the change you suggested, but the bot still remains silent like before.

Comment: If you know your own chatID, make some tests sending message to you. Are you sure that webhook is set correctly?

Comment: got hold of the chat id, trying that now

Comment: Ok, I am able to send myself messages knowing the chat_id. I think my webhooks is set correctly (I did exactly what I wrote in the question), but something must be broken because it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Put the code to send a message like 'ok' to you at top of your script. Then write something on telegram: if you receive 'OK' your webhook is ok, otherwise it is not.

Comment: Tried that and it doesn't work, before I was sending myself messages by manually refreshing the php script

Comment: It is strange. Are you sure the webhook is set and that your script is at the exactly webhook location?

Comment: positive 100% sure, I just set it up again for the 11th time to no avail.

Comment: I put your exact test code at top of my webhook script and it works. I think you have a problem with your webhook setting. It is https? Can you provide the real webhook url? To set webhook url, I use this command from terminal: `curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT_TOKEN>/setWebhook -d url='WEBHOOK_URL' jq .` Tried also now and it works for me.

Comment: I'll try now above url, so if you receive a msg... it's me

Comment: yup, got a message

Comment: I have tried with it. I got `{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook is already set"}` ... So probably you have no change :( but try now to send a message...

Comment: nothing ;_; It's possible that I have to something particular in the site's control panel? (using plesk)

Comment: Try to comment all code before the send message line ( except $bot_id and $chat_id), then place a `die()` after sending test msg. Then try again sending a message.

Comment: You have received a message now? I have simulated a api request.

Comment: made the changes (I have updated the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/WULTrWST), but I don't think I received your message, but I was messing with the script, so I could have missed it. Still getting nothing after sending a message

Comment: If you agree, I can temporary set webhook to my temp script, then I'll make some tests. But I need to subscribe to your bot for that.

Comment: You have received one or more "Test" messages?

Comment: write a message and see if you have a reply

Comment: Yes, I get "TEST" after sending a message.

Comment: Probably you have received a “UNABLE TO PARSE REQUEST” . Try to send a message now.

Comment: I got the “UNABLE TO PARSE REQUEST” and after sending a message I now get the message json.

Comment: Perfect. I have reset your original webhook. [Here](http://pastebin.com/yKCZ2GTi) there is exact code that I have used. Try it on your webhook script to see if it works.

Comment: Refreshing the script gets me the “UNABLE TO PARSE REQUEST”, still nothing if I write something :(

Comment: So it seems you have some problem receiving POST requests on your own site? You have used `file_get_contents('php://input')` before?

Comment: It's possible, I've never user `file_get_contents('php://input')`.

Comment: Do I have to do something in the site's control panel? Or should I ask the hosting service?

Comment: I correct myself, because even without `file_get_contents` you must receive "UNABLE TO PARSE REQUEST". It seems that telegram API can't comunicate with your server. I don't understand why this happen. Maybe a problem with https, but it is strange, because Chrome allow https requests to your site. You can try with a different service (openshift, i.e.).

Comment: You can see apache logs? Just to see what happen at telegram requests.

Comment: just looked and I see: "[Mon Mar 28 13:38:12 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?"
And I'm gettting the feeling that something's wrong with the certificate...

Comment: yes, I think you are right. I'm not expert on SSL :(

Comment: Me neighter, but maybe it's possible that I know what went wrong. I'll work on it and update here if I succeed. Thanks again for the tremendous help though!

Comment: I did it! It was the web application firewall. Turning it off makes the bot work. I'll edit things and explain better when I manage (let's hope I do) to create an excetion for the telegram bot to leave it on.